# Laravel 4: artisan queue:listen does not work

Tags: laravel, queue, hosting

when is use the artisan queue:listen or queue:work command i get this error:

[InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "queue" namespace.

I use OVH Shared Hosting (Pro).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your version of Laravel doesn't have the queue commands installed?  Try running the list command to see what's available

```
$ php artisan list
```

Comment: But the problem you're having isn't on localhost, it's on your remote server -- so step one is checking if artisan on the remote server has what you want.

Comment: its the same artisan file. i think the problem is that i have only webhosting and something is missing on the server.